# Style popups differently depending on the clicked layer using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am currently trying to give my popups different background based on the layer they are found in (i.e. I have a layer called Indigenous Sites where I would like the background of the popup to be different from the other layers).

I have tried giving the popup a className but I am not sure how to call it properly in the CSS.

Below is a sample of the popup script in my html document (script for 2 different layers popups):

```
// popup for the Other European Sites layer 
map.on('click', 'Other European Sites', function (e) {
new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML('<h2>' + 'European Site' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.placeName + '</p>' + 
        '<h2>' + 'Story' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.Story + '</p>' + 
        '<h2>' + 'Latitude' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.latitude + '</p>'  + 
        '<h2>' + 'Longitude' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.longitude + '</p>')
    .addTo(map);
});

// popup for the Other Indigenous Sites layer
map.on('click', 'Other Indigenous Sites', function (e) {
new mapboxgl.Popup({className: 'popupCustom'})
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML('<h2>' + 'Indigenous Site' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.placeName + '</p>' + 
        '<h2>' + 'Story' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.Story + '</p>' + 
        '<h2>' + 'Latitude' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.latitude + '</p>'  + 
        '<h2>' + 'Longitude' + '</h2>' + 
        '<p>' + e.features[0].properties.longitude + '</p>')
    .addTo(map);
});
```

Here is my current CSS that gives all of my popups the same background:

```
.mapboxgl-popup-content {
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

How would I go about assigning the popups different classNames and calling them in the CSS so that I can have different backgrounds for each layer?

Thanks so much for any input!

Comment: (I don't understand the close vote for "too broad". This question is perfectly specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The className is a CSS class name that will be applied to the popup container (which contains the "mapboxgl-popup-content" element). So if you want your "Other Indigenous Sites" layer to have, say, yellow popups, you could do this:

```
.mapboxgl-popup-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.popupCustom .mapboxgl-popup-content {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Note however that this functionality was only very [recently added](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/6502) and I don't think it has been released yet. (It's not in the [published docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup)).

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking this was how it should be formatted but it didn't seem to work! So that makes sense that it has not been released yet :) I was able to figure out a way around it, by putting a div with a class inside of setHTML around my content. Thanks again! :)